# How to use Google Maps in Cordova app

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) instruction. This examle works perfectly in browser. But when I start my app in the android phone it alert me that "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Obtaining_Key".

My key is allowed requests from any referers (*).

What the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works when I remove '*' from referers. So now my browser key referer is empty.